# How to handle OAuthAccessTokenException in facebook api searches

Tags: facebook

I'm using Facebook API for searching. For example if I want to search for 'Conti' i get thsi url: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=%22Conti%22&type=post

In this particular case, and others, instead of getting the list of results, I get this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthAccessTokenException",
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource."
   }
}
```

why is this? should i get a token in order to the get the results?

**UPDATE**

Do I **need** to register an app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the ***access token*** first, have a look at this tutorial:

- [Facebook Graph API — getting access tokens](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/)

Comment: OK, I'll read it, but let me say hat I just want to make some queries, not registering an app. I have no users more than me.

Comment: @Juanjo do you want to just play with the queries from the browser without running them programatically? If you need to do that programatically you need an app (and app doesn't necessary mean you need to have actual facebook app, you will just receive api key so you can make api calls).

Comment: @Juanjo I don't know. What are you trying to achieve? If you just want to run couple queries in a browser you can do that without an app. Otherwise app is probably required.